# Where can I find my (current shell process') PID?

Tags: macos, unix, zsh, pid

I'm on OS X using ZSH (have lots of homebrew stuff, too).

I'd like to know the PID of my current terminal.

(I'm learning more about process management on *nix systems, pstree and the like, and so this is more an academic question vs. a specific use case I'm trying to solve)

EDIT: to clarify, I'm referring to the process that is running my current terminal/commandline.

Comment: What you're looking for is the PID of your current *shell process*.  In your case, that's going to be a `zsh` process.  The terminal doesn't have a PID.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what I was looking for. Updating the Question to be more searchable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The special variable `$$` is the current pid of the shell you are running, for any Bourne compatible (and, so, POSIX) shell.

Comment: And for csh and tcsh (and Perl).

Comment: Works in Ruby too

Comment: `$fish_pid` (though `$$` will warn you, and tell you about `$fish_pid`)